# How to use a custom toggle switch in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile as my framework and I do not like the look of the default toggle switch. I wish to use a purely CSS switch. I have found some great examples that I would like to use (basically a square switch with the ability to see both texts at the same time but show which one is active). I have even just copied and pasted the code into my code and it is always completely distorted, not even recognizable. I am starting to believe it is not possible.

If you know of a way can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Show us one of the examples.

Comment: http://ui-cloud.com/toggle-switches/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the INPUT elements, set data-role="none" to tell jQM to ignore them:

```
<input data-role="none" type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="month" id="month" />
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hetkajgb/1/)**